# How is protein cavity centre related to binding?

Tags: bioinformatics, protein-binding

I am confused and I have the following questions:
1. What are (in the context of article below) protein cavity centres?
2. How are they related to binding?

([Automated identification of protein-ligand interaction features using Inductive Logic Programming: a hexose binding case study](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/13/162), Santos et a. 2012)

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed. Yet you might want to add a bit more information and references.

Comment: no need to get hostile. There is a reason number of votes required for closing/putting on hold question. Regarding question: OP, do you have any reference to the phrase used? Isn't "cavity center" is just central point of given cavity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can find under the table with cavity centers in [pdf version of this article](http://www.biomedcentral.com/content/pdf/1471-2105-13-162.pdf):

> The table lists the protein’s PDB ID, the ligand considered and the specified cavity center. 22 ligands are similar to hexoses in shape and/or size. **The cavity center is the centroid of the reported PDB atom numbers.**

And a little later:

> The binding-site center is computed as the
>   hexose pyranose ring centroid for the positive examples,
>   and as the ligand or empty pocket centroid for the negative
>   ones. The hexose pyranose-ring atoms are located up to
>   2.9
>    ̊
>   A away from the ring’s centroid. Since some atomic
>   interactions can be important up to 7
>    ̊
>   A [22], we consider
>   the binding-site as all protein atoms present within a 10
>    ̊
>   A radius sphere around the binding center. All other atoms
>   are discarded.

So basically @aandreev is right. You can read about centroids [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid)

Comment: I could not understand the head or tail of this, can you please tell me if there is any site which clearly explains these calculations?? I am not a biology or chemistry student, I am a computer science student, but my research field is bioinformatics... So i am having a lot of trouble trying to grasp what this thing means....

Comment: Could you be more specific, about your problems?

Comment: like where would I find information (calculation and explanations) of obtaining centroids of bonding sites of ligands, I want to know about these binding mechanisms and how these calculations are carried out..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_binding, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Geometric_centers

Comment: no no, I am probably not able to explain what I am having a problem with. Like what I want to know is that how did you obtain this fact "  The hexose pyranose-ring atoms are located up to 2.9 ̊ A away from the ring’s centroid. " . How did you obtain the the ring centroid, from which database and how did you calculate this, I know the general formula for centroid, how did you find it for the ligands

Comment: Well, if those guys didn't write it there, they probably thought of it as details - used standard formulas and atomic coordinates.

Comment: I did not understand what you meant by thought of it as details, how do one obtain these coordinates and calculate the cavity centres ?? They mentioned about a database, but could not find anything valuable, or probably I did not understand..

Comment: Atomic coordinate are in PDB files of proteins.

Comment: Sir , I could not find the atomic coordinates in the pdb files, can you tell me how to get the atomic coordinates?

Comment: @rishika https://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimera/docs/UsersGuide/tutorials/pdbintro.html