# Questions regarding a particular paper

Tags: biochemistry, bioinformatics, structural-biology

With respect to the following paper:

[Automated identification of protein-ligand interaction features using Inductive Logic Programming: a hexose binding case study](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/13/162)

I have a few questions:

1. in page 2, in the table, what does 501 mean in GLC-501(I searched for GLC-501 in PDB,couldnt find anything)
2. in page 3, in the table, the cavity center column has got two entries, what does that mean? does one entry belong to the protein and another entry to the ligand(left for protein and right for ligand)??

Comment: related http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/31918/how-is-protein-cavity-centre-related-to-binding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. 501 denotes 501<sup>st</sup> residue in the corresponding PDB entry — 1BDG. See [here](http://marid.bioc.cam.ac.uk/credo/structures/1BDG)
2. A single protein can have multiple cavities (see [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2811767/)) and the multiple entries denote centres of different cavities.

Comment: so why exactly two has been given? Has this paper calculated these centers or are these available somewhere?

Comment: and why is a number given to a residue? What does that imply?

Comment: @user3237995 I am not an expert in this but I think all ligand residues are numbered in the PDB file. Just a way of listing the number of entities I guess. From [this page](http://deposit.rcsb.org/format-faq-v1.html):  *The ligand is assigned a unique residue number within chain to which it is bound. The residue that binds the ligand retains its standard name in both coordinate and SEQRES records.*

Comment: and why only two numbers listed?

Comment: @user3237995 Regarding your first comment. Perhaps they are interested in checking all possible binding sites in the protein. And why 2 sites; perhaps there were not more. Note that some have three as well

Comment: @user3237995 They have possibly taken this data from Nassif et al. *Their negative dataset consists of 80 PDB examples: 22 binding sites that bind hexose-like ligands (e.g. hexose or fructose derivatives, 6-carbon molecules, and molecules similar in shape to hexoses), 27 other-ligand binding sites and 31 non-binding sites. The non-binding sites are sur- face pockets that look like binding sites but are not known to bind any ligand. The negative dataset is presented in Table 2 (non-hexose binding sites) and Table 3 (non- binding sites)*

Comment: one more question, is L-glutamate a ligand??

Comment: @user3237995 In some cases it is; for example, in glutamate receptors.

Comment: how is it different in different cases

Comment: @user3237995 L-glutamate can be a part of the polypeptide chain also. In some cases it acts as a ligand.